# What type of value gets passed to setState function?

Tags: reactjs

I saw a React training video with the following code:

```
const [darkTheme, setDarkTheme] = useState(true)
  
function toggleTheme() { 
    setDarkTheme(prevDarkTheme => !prevDarkTheme)
}
```

In the last line, what is being passed as a parameter to the setDarkTheme function?  I thought a function needs a single value so can't tell if that is an arrow function that is evaluated before passing it, or what.

Comment: A function is being passed as the single value: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: In the last line, what is being passed as a parameter to the setDarkTheme function? An arrow function that has as parameter the previous value of `darkTheme`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` accepts either a value or a function

and when it gets a function that function will be called with the previous state

and note that it's very recommended to always pass a function to make sure you are changing the state correctly

DONT DO

```
    setDarkTheme(!prevDarkTheme)
```

DO

```
    setDarkTheme(prevDarkTheme => !prevDarkTheme)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setDarkTheme(prevDarkTheme => !prevDarkTheme)
```

`prevDarkTheme` here is actual value of this state. We should use function here when there can be a possibility that something else can change this state in meantime. By using `prevDarkTheme` you are always sure that it is the latest value. You can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

Answer (score -1):

its the current value in state variable. in this case it will be `true`

```
function toggleTheme() { 
    setDarkTheme((prevDarkTheme /* true */ ) => !prevDarkTheme /* !true -> false*/) // false
}
```